# Combining 2D Arrays from CSV Files with Same Structure

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am trying to add two arrays `$arraydata1` and `$arraydata2` to get the array `$result`. But it shows the result as if `$result=$arraydata1;`, not as
`$result=$arraydata1+$arraydata2;`.

Here is the array I am trying to add after getting it from the CSV file and storing it in different array type variable.

```
$result = array();
$arraydata1 = array();
$arraydata2 = array();
$key1 = array("itemid","itembrand","itemname","itemmodel","itemdesc","itemtype","itemprice","itemimgfolder","itemimage");
$key2 = array("itemid","itembrand","itemname","itemmodel","itemdesc","itemtype","itemprice","itemimgfolder","itemimage");
foreach (file('data/dell/data.csv') as $key => $str)
{
    if ($key == 0) continue;  // to skip headings of the csv file
    $values = str_getcsv($str, "\t", '', '');
    $arraydata1[] = array_combine($key1, $values);
} // to store first array data

foreach (file('data/hp/data.csv') as $key => $str)
{
    if ($key == 0) continue;  // to skip headings of the csv file
    $values = str_getcsv($str, "\t", '', '');
    $arraydata2[] = array_combine($key2, $values);
}

$result = $arraydata2+$arraydata2; // result the combination of the two arrays
```

Everything else is working fine. I have also tried `array_combine()` but it did not work either.

Comment: Yeah `$result = array_merge($arraydata2,$arraydata1);` is alternate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the possible duplicate comment suggests, I think the answer is to use use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) rather than `+`, but why not just store them all in the same array to begin with?

```
$keys = array("itemid","itembrand","itemname","itemmodel","itemdesc","itemtype","itemprice","itemimgfolder","itemimage");

$files = array('data/dell/data.csv', 'data/hp/data.csv');

foreach ($files as $file) {
    foreach (file($file) as $key => $str) {
        if ($key == 0) continue;  // to skip headings of the csv file
        $values = str_getcsv($str, "\t", '', '');
        $result[] = array_combine($keys, $values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight...

Comment: I could do it by `$result = array_merge($arraydata2,$arraydata1);`. Using your code I am not able to print the data in desired way as I got with array `$result` in merge case. For example I cannot `echo result[0]['itemname']` now.

Comment: Thank you, **Don't Panic**. It's working. I am using your method to use it in jQuery-UI autocomplete. Due to you my 120 line code will be reduced to 8-10 lines. Thank you!

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I was afraid of the error but your code is with no error. Thanks